# One certificate for multiple projects - GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate

I have a certificate in one of my GCP project, and I want to use the same certificate in a different project without having to create a new one, is it  possible?
I couldn't find any information about cross-project certificate in the documentation.
(The certificate will be used in the load balancer if it makes any difference)

Comment: I am curious on why you want to do this?

Comment: I want to separate my production environment from my qa so I have created different projects for each under my organisation

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use the same SSL certificate in multiple load balancers that are in different projects, you will need to upload your own SSL certificate.